# Printing nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I am a newbie to this array thing as still learning. Need to print this nested array. Pls guide me how to do it as when trying to print it is not recognized.

```
$args = array(
        'pUserId'=>"veenu",
        "pPassword" => "somePass",
    "pCode" => 381,
    "pCity" => "DELHI",
        $pIn = array("TypeCode" => 22,"Subtype" => "21"));
```

The way I am trying to print is below

```
print_r($args[pIn] -> TypeCode);
```

Error when trying to print is "Undefined index: pIn" and "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Your trying to print the entire array?

Comment: What is the relation between `$args` and `$pIn` and the `TypeCode`?

Comment: should be "pIn" => array("TypeCode" => 22,"Subtype" => "21")

Comment: I am trying to pass this $args variable to one of the function which has this array defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting `$pIn` as a key, but it is not defined. But if you want to put just `pIn` (as string), you don't need to express it in a variable.

What you need is simply

```
$args = array(
        "pUserId" => "veenu",
        "pPassword" => "somePass",
        "pCode" => 381,
        "pCity" => "DELHI",
        "pIn" => array(
                "TypeCode" => 22,
                "Subtype" => "21")
         );
```

As `$args` is now a multidimensional array, you will be able to get the TypeCode like this:

```
echo $args["pIn"]["TypeCode"];
```

Answer (score 0):

1.From what I see, you want to have a key pLn pointing to the nested array. This is how you do it:

```
"pIn" => array("TypeCode" => 22,"Subtype" => "21")
```

2.It's a good idea when using keys to enclose them in single quotes:

```
 print_r($args['pIn']['TypeCode']);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
echo $args[$pIn]['TypeCode'];
```

This is a multi-dimensional array.

It has a parent array and an array with key `$pIn`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have it written, you are assigning an array to the variable $pIn and including it in $args but not as an index. Your array as defined looks like:

```
array(5) {
  ["pUserId"]=>
  string(5) "veenu"
  ["pPassword"]=>
  string(8) "somePass"
  ["pCode"]=>
  int(381)
  ["pCity"]=>
  string(5) "DELHI"
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["TypeCode"]=>
    int(22)
    ["Subtype"]=>
    string(2) "21"
  }
}
```

You probably want:

```
$args = array(
        'pUserId'=>"veenu",
        "pPassword" => "somePass",
    "pCode" => 381,
    "pCity" => "DELHI",
    "pIn" => array("TypeCode" => 22,"Subtype" => "21"));

    print_r($args["pIn"]["TypeCode"]);
```

Notice how the print_r accesses the element you want.